# Mysql Update from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE `examination_lower` 
    SET `Mathematics`=Mathematics.Admno,
        `English`=English.total,
        `Kiswahili`=Kiswahili.total,
        `Science`=Science.total, 
        `Religion`=Religion.total,
        `Social_studies`=Social_studies.total,
        `Total`=0 
WHERE examination_lower.admno=Admno
```

Mathematics, English, Kiswahili, etc. are all tables with total and admno as common columns.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this: (skipping some columns for brevity)

```
UPDATE examination_lower, Mathematics, English, Kiswahili -- (continue on)
    SET examination_lower.Mathematics = Mathematics.total,
        examination_lower.English = English.total,
        examination_lower.Kiswahili = Kiswahili.total
WHERE examination_lower.admno = Mathematics.admno
AND   examination_lower.admno = English.admno
AND   examination_lower.admno = Kiswahili.admno
```